# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ros_control"

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to catkin_make my workspace in ROS Kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04. I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ros_control" with
  any of the following names:

    ros_controlConfig.cmake
    ros_control-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ros_control" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  test_test/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'ros_control'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ros_control" with
  any of the following names:

    ros_controlConfig.cmake
    ros_control-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "ros_control" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ros_control
  ros_controllers
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)


catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES test_test
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS ros_control ros_controllers roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

I have tried the following but it did not help:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-effort-controllers
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller
```

Update:

I installed this package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control ros-kinetic-ros-controllers
```

The issue persists but now I am getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: package "test_test" should not depend on metapackage "ros_control" but on its packages instead
WARNING: package "test_test" should not depend on metapackage "ros_controllers" but on its packages instead
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330730/could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22ros_control%22/) by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2019-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-14**:
How did you install `ros_control`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-15**:
I believe the issue is that OP is depending on a metapackage directly. That is not supported and should not be done.

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-08-15**:
@gvdhoorn Could you please elaborate?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-15**:
[Metapackage](https://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages)

> [...] do not install files (other than their package.xml manifest) and they do not contain any tests, code, files, or other items usually found in packages.

and

> A metapackage simply references one or more related packages which are loosely grouped together.

So, it's a package of packages and isn't meant to be depended on. You should depend on one of the packages that's contained *in* the metapackage, not the metapackage itself.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I guess you are missing ROS-Control package.

Maybe try this,

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control ros-kinetic-ros-controllers
```

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-08-15**:
That did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to expand on my comment (I'll reiterate it first):

[Metapackage](https://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages)

> [...] do not install files (other than their package.xml manifest) and they do not contain any tests, code, files, or other items usually found in packages.

and

> A metapackage simply references one or more related packages which are loosely grouped together.

So, it's a package of packages and isn't meant to be depended on. You should depend on one of the packages that's contained *in* the metapackage, not the metapackage itself.

Look at one of the tests in `ros_control`, for example the [controller_manager_tests](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/tree/melodic-devel/controller_manager_tests) package. You'll notice that in its [CMakeLists.txt file](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/melodic-devel/controller_manager_tests/CMakeLists.txt), it doesn't depend on the `ros_control` *metapackage*. Instead, it depends on the package that it's using (testing in this case).

So, you need to depend on the package that you're using not the metapackage.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1